# Android Broadcast Notification with Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, azure, push-notification

I'm trying to broadcast a message to all users of an Android app using Azure notification hub. It works when sending a "data" notification but not a "notification" notification. I'm guessing it's because the "notification" type requires a "to" parameter? Do you have to register a "all users" tag with GCM before this will work?

OK, I was under the impression that you had to include the "to" field when sending "notification" type notifications. Apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register your subscribers to some tag that will be using for a broadcast. Next, you can debug your notifications using Debug pane on the Notification Hub dashboard - there you can see the random broadcast which will be distributed randoly, and not random. If you select the former, you should provide the tag. So, it can be "all users", or "news", or whatever else.[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried the "notification" without the "to" field and it worked.

Comment: Awesome! Please mark the question as answered for a future use, thanks.